# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object at PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to use some remember me class , now the problem is i get

`Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`

and i dont get any error's :

index.php :

```
    try {
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ibids', 'root', '');
    } 

catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        printf ($e);
    }

$storage = new Rememberme_Storage_PDO($connection);
$rememberMe = new Rememberme($storage);
```

i send the connection to this file :
**pdo.php**
 and using there this code :

```
class Rememberme_Storage_PDO extends Rememberme_Storage_DB {

  /**
   *
   * @var PDO
   */
  protected $connection;
  public function getConnection() {
    return $this->connection;
  }

  public function setConnection(PDO $connection) {

   try  {
     $this->connection = $connection;
        } 
    catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            printf ($e);
        }
  }
}
```

And i have the error here on this function :

** **this function inside Rememberme_Storage_PDO class**

```
   public function storeTriplet($credential, $token, $persistentToken, $expire=0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->tableName}({$this->credentialColumn}, " .
           "{$this->tokenColumn}, {$this->persistentTokenColumn}, " .
           "{$this->expiresColumn}) VALUES(?, SHA1(?), SHA1(?), ?)";
    $query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

    if(!$query->execute(array($credential, $token, $persistentToken, date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expire))))
        {
        die('excute faild');
        }
  }
```

says :

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in F:\wamp\www\rememberme-master\src\Rememberme\Storage\PDO.php on line 44
```

I am newbie at PDO , what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: When you var_dump($this->connection), what do you get?

Comment: nothing i keep get the same error , and not any other errors , i tryed die , var_dump , catch , everything show the same error.. BTW this good way to make a connection with the getConenction method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like don't have a constructor. If you pass a variable when using `new` it is passed to the constructor and not a `setter`. So when using this:

```
$storage = new Rememberme_Storage_PDO($connection);
```

… you need in `Rememberme_Storage_PDO`:

```
public function __construct(\PDO $connection) {
    $this->setConnection($connection);
}
```

Comment: Working perfect , Thanks you so mnuch you saved my day :). cant tick Answered need wait more 4 minutes, and i will aprove thanks again.

Comment: Meh owned by 30 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $this->connection is not an object .. which is rather obvious since you are not using the setConnection public function..

I only see you trying to pass the connection object to the constructor, but there is no constructor that actually stores it in the `$this->connection` property.

Perhaps

```
$storage = new Rememberme_Storage_PDO($connection);
```

should be:

```
$storage = new Rememberme_Storage_PDO();
$storage->setConnection($connection);
```